# Pentaho data integration run exec procedure , it is running fine using sqlplus.

Tags: pentaho, pentaho-data-integration

I want to run

```
EXEC MANAGE_TEST
```

in petaho

IN SQLPLUS : EXEC MANAGE_TEST run fine

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it solved ,

Instead of

```
EXEC MANAGE_TEST
```

I used

```
CALL MANAGE_TEST()
```

It worked .